# PHP code cannot be executed

Tags: apache-httpd, php

My php code doesn't work, the code is displayed in the browser instead of being executed, the apache is going up normally, the info.php doesn't work either, any idea what to do or install I'm using Arch

Comment: You haven't added the [php handler](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Apache_HTTP_Server) to the Apache configuration

Comment: You may want to give us info about your server so we can tell you which command to run to get such extensions added.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142172/apache-shows-php-code-instead-of-executing-it

Comment: @roaima I haven't some idea for add php handler in apache config

Comment: @OldTimer I have tested some solutions and it not work for me

Comment: @roaima I fixed adding this code in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf  LoadModule php_module modules/libphp.so
AddHandler php-script .php

Comment: Please do not write extra information into the comments. It's hard to track and comments can get deleted without notice. Instead please update your question ([edit] it) so all the detail is in one place. Make it easy for people to help you

Comment: Or if what you've written here solved your problem, write it as your own answer - which you can then accept so people can see your question is resolved

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Apache_HTTP_Server#PHP):

To enable PHP, add these lines to `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`:

```
LoadModule <other modules...> php_module modules/libphp.so 
AddHandler php-script .php
Include <other includes...> conf/extra/php_module.conf
```